# count consecutive occurrence in data step

Tags: sas

```
Pos Series Res
--- ------ ---
A   1      1
A   1      1
A   1      0
A   1      -1
.
.
B   3      1
B   3     -1
```

Only possible values of `Res` are `1,0,-1`. My goal is to count the number of consecutive `K` occurrence of `1` or `-1` for each series, where `K` is defined by user.

example:
`1 1 -1 1 1 1 0 0 1`

`K = 2`, output is `3`.

`K = 3`, output is `1`.

`K > 3`, output is `0`.

**Question**

If k is fixed, then I can do it using `lag`. But I don't how to deal with this with a dynamic `k`.

```
data Want;
   set Have;
   prev1 = lag1(Res);
   prev2 = lag2(Res);
   prev3 = lag3(Res);
   if first.Pos  or Series = 1 then call missing(prev1,prev2,prev3);
   if Series = 2 then call missing(prev2,prev3);
   if Series = 3 then call missing(prev3);
   N = sum(of prev:);
run;

proc sql noprint;
   select count(*), N
   from WANT
   group by N;
quit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this uses no lags.

```
data have;
input Pos $ Series Res;
datalines;
A   1      1
A   1      1
A   1      0
A   1      -1
A   1      1
A   1      1
A   1      1
A   1      0
B   3      1
B   3     -1
B   3      1
B   3      1
;;;;
run;

%let k=2;
data want;
  set have;
  array inRow[-1:1] seriesM1 seriesZero seriesP1;
  by pos series res notsorted;
  if first.res then consec=0;
  if first.series then do;
    inRow[-1]=0;
    inRow[1]=0;
  end;
  consec+1;
  if consec >= &k and res ne 0 then inRow[res]+1;
  if last.series then output;
run;
```

I make some assumptions here as to how you handle 'k in a row' with longer rows, but it should give the right answer for a reasonable assumption (for any M > K, you have (M-K)+1 K-in-a-rows).

Basically, you can use the BY statement with NOTSORTED to count runs in a variable, because if it's NOTSORTED it will reset FIRST. each time it hits a new value regardless of the order of those values.  So you take advantage of that, and tada, you know how many in a row you've seen so far.  Then compare that to `k` and you're set.

Comment: why `and res ne 0`? Seems no difference without this.

Comment: It still works without that, but you explicitly asked for -1 and 1 not 0... I left 0 in the array because it is easier to leave it in than to exclude it.